# Having a figure caption on the side of a centerd image

Tags: css

By the default a caption is below the image.

```
<figure>
<img src="some_img.jpg"> 
<figcaption>Some Image Caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

If you need the caption on the side you can just use `dispaly: inline` for `figcaption`.

Then you can center both with `text-align: center`.

But how can you align just the image box on the center, while keeping the caption on the side of it?

Like this: [mock up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCicP.jpg)

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for...do you have a design mock-up we can see? Do you mean like this? - http://jsfiddle.net/cjsh4a67/1/

Comment: no, like this: https://i.imgur.com/8jRbG6u.jpg the image is centered, the caption is on the side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to position the `figcaption` absolutely.

```css
figure {
  border: 1px solid #663399;
  background: #bada55;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
figure img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  /* values below can be amended as required */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(100%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-c-200-200-6.jpg" />
  <figcaption>Some Image Caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought about it, the problem of this solution is that you need to change the values for every image with different size. (if you want the caption to be at a fixed distance from the right border of the image)

Comment: You would have to use an extra 'wrapper' if your images are different sizes. - http://jsfiddle.net/y3fuv1b2/2/